# iPhone SDK loading screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, loading

I have a view in my app where I use a very large photo that is Hi-Res and takes a bit of time to load. How do I put a loading screen while this is happening? The kind of loading screen with the spinning loading wheel so that the app does not look like it has frozen? Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit:** Note that I am simply loading the image from the main bundle and not a URL

Comment: How are you loading the image? With an NSURLRequest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out these Open-Source activity indicators.

---

[image]

**[TDHUDProgressBar](http://github.com/tmdvs/TDHUDProgressBar)**

Looks like Tweetie's/Twitter's Progress bar.

---

[image]

**[MBProgressHUD](http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD)**

A view that appears and contains a Activity Indicator, much like the Private Class `UIProgressHUD`.

Comment: Is MBProgressHUD okay? As `UIProgressHUD` is a private class.

Answer (score 1):

Put an activity indicator (the spinning wheel) into your view and hide it when your hi-res image has finished loading.

Comment: will this run even while the view is loading?